# AppFlow deployment error: Destination object for the destination connector can not be updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-appflow, serverless.com

I am getting the following error when doing subsequent deployments of AppFlow:

> AWS::AppFlow::FlowUpdate Flow request failed due to:[Destination object for the destination connector can not be updated]

Below is the serverless.com .yml / cloudformation template, please note that the destination object does not change from deployment to deployment.

```
        SalesforceSubscriptionToEventBridge: 
            Type: 'AWS::AppFlow::Flow'
            Properties:
                FlowName: 'SalesforceSubscriptionToEventBridge'                
                Description: 'Salesforce Subscription Platform Event to EventBridge'
                TriggerConfig:
                    TriggerType: 'Event'
                SourceFlowConfig:
                    ConnectorType: 'Salesforce'
                    ConnectorProfileName: 'SalesforceToEventBridge'
                    SourceConnectorProperties:
                        Salesforce:
                            Object: 'SubscriptionEvent__e' # Salesforce Platform Event
                DestinationFlowConfigList:
                    -   ConnectorType: 'EventBridge'
                        DestinationConnectorProperties:
                            EventBridge:
                                Object: 'data' # this remains unchanged from deployment to deployment. Destination object is aws.partner/appflow/salesforce.com/[AWS::AccountId]/data
                Tasks:
                    -   TaskType: 'Filter'
                        ConnectorOperator:
                            Salesforce: 'PROJECTION'
                        SourceFields:
                            - 'Name'
                    -   TaskType: 'Map'
                        ConnectorOperator:
                            Salesforce: 'NO_OP'
                        DestinationField: 'reference'
                        SourceFields:
                            - 'Name'
                        TaskProperties:
                            -   Key: SOURCE_DATA_TYPE
                                Value: string
                            -   Key: DESTINATION_DATA_TYPE
                                Value: string
        SalesforcePartnerEventBus:
            Type: 'AWS::Events::EventBus'
            Properties:
                EventSourceName:
                    Fn::Join: ['', ['aws.partner/appflow/salesforce.com/',Ref: 'AWS::AccountId','/data']]
                Name:
                    Fn::Join: ['', ['aws.partner/appflow/salesforce.com/',Ref: 'AWS::AccountId','/data']]
            DependsOn : 'SalesforceSubscriptionToEventBridge'
```

Or the generated template in JSON format is below:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "The AWS CloudFormation template for this Serverless application",
  "Resources": {
    "SalesforceSubscriptionToEventBridge": {
      "Type": "AWS::AppFlow::Flow",
      "Properties": {
        "FlowName": "SalesforceSubscriptionToEventBridge",
        "Description": "Salesforce Subscription Platform Event to EventBridge",
        "TriggerConfig": {
          "TriggerType": "Event"
        },
        "SourceFlowConfig": {
          "ConnectorType": "Salesforce",
          "ConnectorProfileName": "SalesforceToEventBridge",
          "SourceConnectorProperties": {
            "Salesforce": {
              "Object": "SubscriptionEvent__e"
            }
          }
        },
        "DestinationFlowConfigList": [
          {
            "ConnectorType": "EventBridge",
            "DestinationConnectorProperties": {
              "EventBridge": {
                "Object": "data"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "Tasks": [
          {
            "TaskType": "Filter",
            "ConnectorOperator": {
              "Salesforce": "PROJECTION"
            },
            "SourceFields": [
              "Name"
            ]
          },
          {
            "TaskType": "Map",
            "ConnectorOperator": {
              "Salesforce": "NO_OP"
            },
            "DestinationField": "reference",
            "SourceFields": [
              "Name"
            ],
            "TaskProperties": [
              {
                "Key": "SOURCE_DATA_TYPE",
                "Value": "string"
              },
              {
                "Key": "DESTINATION_DATA_TYPE",
                "Value": "string"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "CustomerPlatformSFPartnerEventBus": {
      "Type": "AWS::Events::EventBus",
      "Properties": {
        "EventSourceName": {
          "Fn::Join": ["",["aws.partner/appflow/salesforce.com/",
              {"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},"/data"]]
        },
        "Name": {
          "Fn::Join": ["",["aws.partner/appflow/salesforce.com/",
              {"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},"/data"]]
        }
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "SalesforceSubscriptionToEventBridge"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you reviewed the transformed template?  You might get more feedback if you posted the transformed template.

Comment: @TimBassett ok, I've added the generated template to the original question.